# Sharepoint Online - How to get content type column names in a web part

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a content type, let's say "invoices" and several columns such as "clientName", "clientAddress", "clientRefCode" etc. I also created a Document library that I connected to the content type.

The project i work in consists on developping a search engine using a specific component web part. Once created, I tried some stuffs to display information concerning context but without a lot of success...

My actual objective consists on retrieving the column names and their type (single line text, multiline, choice / select) in order to build a form using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rest api to get content type columns. Like this:

```
_api/web/contenttypes(contenttypeid)/fields
```